# How to check if values of 'column1' are within +-20% range of values of 'column2' using Amazon Deequ?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-deequ

So, I'm using Amazon Deequ in spark, and I have a dataframe 'df' with two columns being of type 'Long' or numeric. I simply want to check:

`value(column1) lies between value(column2)-20% and value(column2)+20%` for all rows

I'm not sure what check to put here:

```
val verificationResult: VerificationResult = { VerificationSuite()
  .onData(df)
  .addCheck(
    Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Review Check")
      //.funtionToCheckThis()
    )
  .run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Check`](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/checks/Check.scala) has a method [`satisfies`](https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/fc3b30715570e7e3f558fb7bcc3abe4cff83914d/src/main/scala/com/amazon/deequ/checks/Check.scala#L667) which can take a column expression as condition parameter.

To check whether `column1` is between `-20%column2` and `+20%column2`, you can use expression like:

`|column1 - column2| < 0.20*column2`

or
`column1 between 0.80*column2 and 1.20*column2`:

```
val verificationResult: VerificationResult = {
  VerificationSuite()
    .onData(df)
    .addCheck(
      Check(CheckLevel.Error, "Review Check")
        .satisfies(
          "abs(column1 - column2) <= 0.20 * column2",
          "value(column1) lies between value(column2)-20% and value(column2)+20%"
        )
    ).run()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as expected. As an add-on, is there any way Deequ can flag ```only the rows``` that do not meet this check? Like, instead of mentioning ```Failure``` if even a single row fails, can we identify that row, by say, it's value in 'column3'?

Comment: @DebapratimChakraborty as far as I know this is not possible. But to identify the rows you could try to filter in your data df using the negation of the constraint that failed in Deequ.

Comment: Thanks again - that works fine as well. Just one last question - say a check fails in Deequ, it gives a constraint_message like : ```Value: 0.76 does not meet the constraint requirement!```

Does this imply that 76% of my data failed the check, and 24% passed? If not, then is there any way we can get this metric directly from Deequ (%passed, %failed) when we do the check?

Comment: @DebapratimChakraborty `0.76` means "only 76% passed"